# How to create one line and insert text center

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to ask about design in flutter. I don't know how to do it.
I insert the image for your see my draw. Hope your guys can help me.

[image]

Comment: check `Row`, `Divider` and `Text` classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Creating Horizontal line(Divider) around Text Widget**

```
 Row(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: new Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 20.0),
                    child: Divider(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      height: 36,
                    )),
              ),
              Text("OR"),
              Expanded(
                child: new Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 10.0),
                    child: Divider(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      height: 36,
                    )),
              ),
            ]),
```

Answer (score 1):

there is lots of approach to this

1) using something like this

```
Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
              height: 4,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
            child: Text(
              "Or",
              style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
              height: 4,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

2) this code has better performance

```dart
    class TextWithLine extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return CustomPaint(
          size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 100),
          painter: TextWithLinePainter(
            color: Colors.red,
            text: "Or",
            textStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 15,
            ),
            lineColor: Colors.black54,
            lineSize: 1,
            margin: 8,
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class TextWithLinePainter extends CustomPainter {
      String text;
      TextStyle textStyle;
      Color color;
      Color lineColor;
      double lineSize;
      double margin;

      TextWithLinePainter({this.text, this.textStyle, this.color, this.lineColor, this.lineSize, this.margin});

      @override
      void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
        final textSpan = TextSpan(
          text: text,
          style: textStyle,
        );
        final textPainter = TextPainter(
          text: textSpan,
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        );
        textPainter.textAlign = TextAlign.center;

        textPainter.layout(
          minWidth: 0,
          maxWidth: size.width,
        );

        var textW = textPainter.width;
        var textH = textPainter.height;

        textPainter.paint(
          canvas,
          Offset(
            size.width / 2 - textW / 2,
            size.height / 2 - textH / 2,
          ),
        );

        Paint linePainter = Paint()
          ..color = lineColor
          ..isAntiAlias = true
          ..strokeWidth = lineSize;

        var firstLineEndX = size.width / 2 - (textW / 2) - margin;

        canvas.drawLine(
          Offset(0, size.height / 2),
          Offset(firstLineEndX, size.height / 2),
          linePainter,
        );

        var secondLineStartX = (size.width / 2) + (textW / 2) + margin;

        canvas.drawLine(
          Offset(secondLineStartX, size.height / 2),
          Offset(size.width, size.height / 2),
          linePainter,
        );
      }

      @override
      bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this class,

```
class DividerWithText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextStyle textStyle;
  final Color color;

  const DividerWithText({Key key, this.text, this.color, this.textStyle})
      : assert(text != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(child: Divider(color: color)),
        const SizedBox(width: 5.0),
        Text(
          text,
          style: textStyle?.copyWith(color: textStyle.color ?? color) ??
              TextStyle(color: color),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 5.0),
        Expanded(child: Divider(color: color)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Text("Login"),
DividerWithText(
  text: "Or",
  textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
  color: Colors.red,
),
Text("Google"),
```